# How to run my Vue + Node application on static IP

Tags: node.js, vue.js, static-ip-address

I have created an application which I am running on my device with the local IP address. Now what I am trying to do is I want to access it through static IP so that if I am not connected to the same network I can access it through static IP. In turn, I can get this from Google when I type "my static IP" on Google.

Currently my app is running on `localhost:8080` or '192.168.*.*:8080' so whoever is connected to same server over same network is able to see that but I want to do it with static IP.

Comment: Did u get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Now you should have to live this app on Heroku or an EC2 instance, then they will provide a public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

So static IP just means an IP address that doesn't change. This can be local (the 192.168.x.x) or public (where you can access it from anywhere). There are some hosting options, and I'd recommend Heroku.

If this is your first time, you'll need to know some things like setting scripts for "postinstall" or setting up your Procfile, so take a look at this [guide for deploying.](https://medium.com/binarcode/deploying-vue-apps-to-heroku-the-right-way-26b11c1ae5cd)

There are numerous other options as well for deployment with lots of information and tutorials you can Google pretty easily.